# Gimp grid strange behavior - feature or bug?

Tags: gimp

When I create a grid in Gimp (a 32x32px grid with 0x0px offset), the distance between the top edge of the image, and the first grid line, is 31 pixels, almost like the grid starts one pixel above the canvas. The same goes for the left edge.

However, after enabling Snap to Grid, pasted images (with sizes that are multiples of 32x32px) snap to the "correct" grid positions, as if the grid started at the first pixel of the canvas. The drawn grid and the snapping grid do not align. Also, the snapping is dependent on the zoom factor (and maybe on the size of the image being snapped, I'm not sure).

Is this correct behavior? Is this changeable?

I'm using Gimp 2.6.11 on Windows (both 7 and XP).

Image how it looks:
[image]

Comment: I can reproduce this in GIMP 2.6.8 on Ubuntu Linux. Also, it seems that the snapping fluctuates as I drag the selection around -- sometimes it snaps to the actual grid lines, but usually one pixel down and right of them.  Seems like a bug to me.  You might want to [report it](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-introduction-bugs.html).

Comment: [Obligatory...](http://i.imgur.com/3eoAZ.jpg)

Answer (score 4):

Gimp starts to count the pixel from 0, not 1, so 32px are from 0 to 31, 32 to 63, etc...[Coordinate Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OhHc5.jpg)

About the grid snap, it works well for me so i'm not able to reproduce it, I have the same version on Windows 7 x64.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue. Removing/renaming the .gimp-2.8 folder in my home directory fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure this was the following bug: 
https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=588512

Fixed recently - to be precise, Wed May 21 20:43:05 2014 +0200. The fix is available in releases 2.8.12 and newer.

Answer (score 0):

This bug appears to be active in 2.8.10.

The problem seems to be an off-by-one error in the first row, and column of each grid.

The solution seems to be to offset your grid by a negative amount one less than your grid-size. So, for a grid of 32x32, offset by -31x and -31y. This pushes the broken row and column out of your workspace.